# web3.py - AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'get_block'

Tags: web3.py

So... I'm probably being super dumb - but I started using web3.py in a jupyter notebook and it connects to the node just fine... but I can't seem to use any .eth methods as it throws a: `AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'get_block'`

Versions:

- w3.api
  '5.0.0'
- Python: 3.9.1
- OS: osx

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://fullnode.dappnode:8545'))
```

`w3.isConnected()` returns `True`, and I can use w3.api and w3.clientVersion just fine... but when I try to do something eth related I get:

```
>>> w3.eth.get_block('latest')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-70b856a4c410> in <module>
----> 1 w3.eth.get_block('latest')

AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'get_block'
```

or

```
w3.eth.chain_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-9e974a6bb0e9> in <module>
----> 1 w3.eth.chain_id

AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'chain_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all came down to a virtualenv mess. For some reason it was using a globally installed web3 version (`5.0.0`) instead of the documented one that I was following the quickstart for (`latest`).
Nuking the virtualenv and starting from scratch with the new version worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Apparently we installed an older version of Web3 that used to have the method `getBlock`, now deprecated in favor of the `get_block` method.

However I don't know how to upgrade to the latest version, tried using `pip install Web3 --upgrade` but nothing changes.

Comment: It all came down to a virtualenv mess. For some reason it was using a globally installed web3 version (`5.0.0`) instead of the documented one that I was following the quickstart for (`latest`). Nuking the virtualenv and starting from scratch with the new version worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In [web3 v6](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v6_migration.html#snake-case), all camelCase methods were updated to use snake_case. You can check which version of web3 you are using with the following command:

```
python3 -m pip show web3
```

If you see a version < 6.0.0, you will need to upgrade web3.

```
python3 -m pip install web3 -U
```