# getting "Import "web3" could not be resolved" error

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
from web3 import Web3
import json


install_solc("0.8.0")


with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


# Compile our solidity

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "enm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)


# get bytecode

bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]
["object"]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# for connecting to ganache

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://0.0.0.0:7545"))
chain_id = 5777
my_address = "not fill here"
private_key = "not fill here"

# Create the contract in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
```

I'm getting an error while importing web3 as "Import "web3" could not be resolved"

I'm working in the venv and all package install with pip btw.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Does ```import web3``` work for you? The issue may have to do with your web3 version or with the virtual environment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/web3-py-attributeerror-eth-object-has-no-attribute-get-block

Answer (score 2):

It works regardless of the VS Code error, better still you can restart your VS Code and the error will be gone

Answer (score 1):

hi I'm also doing that same course,
its not at all problem unless u installed web3.py successfully
its fine VS code will show it as error but Web3 will work fine when every u run

> > > python deploy.py

[image]in terminal

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't printing anything before I saw this so never would have realized that lol

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't working with the error. So, the solution for me was installing web3 globally on my local system, outside of the virtual env using `pip3 install web3` command. I'm using python3 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

change your version of python interpreter  To " python 3.8.9 "  to fix it.